# Можно ли автоматизировать обрезку изображений на основе одной части

Tags: java, изображения, pdf

Есть задача обработать большое количество pdf макетов присылаемых нам типографией [Пример файла](http://we.tl/wmBJTe1f1X). На основе этого файла надо сделать вот такие перьвю для сайта.

[image: пример изображения]

Можно подумать что всё просто - перегоняешь все пдфки в картинки а после кропаешь их все по одним и тем же координатам и создаешь первьюшки, но проблема в том что зона которую надо вырезать и разрешение самого файла бывает немного разное( Тогда мне пришла в голову идея просто изучить все те 20-30 макетов узнать все размеры и в зависимости от них кропать и выглядело это примерно так

```
BufferedImage img=  cropImage(load, 136, 288, 1024, 1850);
if(load.getHeight()==2471)
    if(load.getWidth()==2400)
    {

        img = cropImage(load,1000,386,1021,1846);


    }
if(load.getHeight()==2400)
    if(load.getWidth()==2505)
    {

        img = cropImage(load,1023,402,1000,1843);


    }
if(load.getHeight()==3300)
    if(load.getWidth()==2550)
    {

        img = cropImage(load,1113,902,1106,1849);


    }
```

Тут же столкнулся с проблемой что примерно 30% макетов имеют одинаковые размеры но разное расположение области которую надо вырезать, например картинка может быть слева а описание справа. Помогите найти способ или скажите куда копать что бы решить данную проблему. Очень начинающий программист знаю только java. Единственная идея которую нашёл это юзать OpenCv но по ней примеры больше на си++ и на английском языке, которых я не знаю.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно определить два ключевых объекта (две части изображения) для определения границ выделяемой области (они будут использоваться в качестве шаблонов) и уже по данным шаблонам искать область изображения, которую необходимо вырезать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный вариант конечно же уступает компьютерному зрению, но тоже имеет право на жизнь